# Slightly tweak paypal user interface

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

Perhaps a stupid question but I have to ask... Im targeting users in a country where PayPal does not support their (the country's) currency type as a billing amount so I changed PayPal `payment.php` page (is this allowed...?) like so:

```
//' TODO: Enter the total Payment Amount within the quotes.
        //' example : $paymentAmount = "15.00";
        //'------------------------------------
        $usd_rate = "13.50"; //I might still add a funtion to get live exchange rate here
        $zar = "50.00";
        $amount = $zar / $usd_rate;
        $amount = round($amount,2);
        $paymentAmount = $amount;
```

The following is working and I am getting this:

[image]

**What I want to do**

Can you see the empty / blank circle on the left...? I would like to add the variable value `$zar` in that circle so it will read something like:

**1st circle (left)**
*$50.00ZAR =*

**2nd circle (right)**
*$3.70 USD*

Answer (score 0):

PayPal does not support this tweak, unfortunately.

But you may want to try putting it in the item information to display on PayPal. The way to put it there depends on the product you use. PayPal docs will provide the info.

https://developer.paypal.com